# Android very long texts inside recyclerview items very laggy

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve fast scrolling because now it is very laggy when the code reaches this:

```
        holderOneElement.noteTitleText.setText(noteItem.getNoteTitle());
        holderOneElement.noteDetailsText.setText(noteItem.getNoteDetails());
```

This code is inside `onBindViewHolder()` of recyclerview.

The fact is I have many (about 30 recyclerview items, and it still growing up) and those two Strings especially noteItem.getNoteDetails() are very long, with width reaching even more than 60000 when I check width with this code:

```
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = holderOneElement.noteDetailsText.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(noteItem.getNoteDetails(), 0, noteItem.getNoteDetails().length(), bounds);
    int tvWidthWithText = bounds.width();
```

My idea is to show only as many `noteItem.getNoteDetails()` text as it can fit in a parent's view with `noteItem.getNoteDetails().replace(start, end)`.

It is Worth mentioning that these two textviews does not need to be showing full strings. If string is longer than text view parent size then it should be as many as it fits.

Maybe then I will not be laggy...

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `I have many (about 30 ..` That is not many. That is nothing. 3000 would not even be many.

Comment: Make a noteItem.getNoteDetailsShort(100) that delivers a certain amount of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pagination and fetch data of a particular range. Like if you have total 300 items, get first 10 first, then next 10, continue till you get all the data

For items description, show max 2 lines in recycler and complete details can be shown in dialog or fragment. Restrict the lines of description text in layout with maxLines attribute.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I was already setting setMaxLines=2 and in fact there was two lines but it was the same laggy